# How to compare inside linq query in a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, foreach

In this foreach loop, I want to find my model with this Condition you see. The problem is I can't compare
`b.GroupId` and `group.GroupId` it says `b.GroupId` is null but the `group.GroupId` is not null I have traced it and it has a value of 1. This is my code

```cs
@foreach (var group in groups.Where(g => g.ParrentId == null))
{
    <div class="tab-pane active animated fadeInRight" id="tab_@group.GroupId">
    var blog = Model.First(b=>b.GroupId==group.GroupId);
}
```

my model

```
@model IEnumerable<DataLayer.Entities.Blog.Blog>

@inject Core.Services.Interfaces.IGroupServices _groupServices;
@{ 
List<DataLayer.Entities.Group.Group> groups = 
_groupServices.getAllGroups();}
```

[image]

as you see group.GroupId is 1 but 'a' is still 0
this is an example of my problem

Comment: look at the image i added to understand my problem

Comment: I tried to understand the image, but I'm confused. I see `a` which is set to 0 but I can't see where it is set to something else. Where is this `a=group.GroupId` line? and what has this a to do with your b in your Where clause?

Answer (score 1):

> but the **group**.GroupId is not null

But as you stated the issues is with **b**, not with **group**. So somewhere in your model there is GroupId with null. It is unclear how to fix that since there are no information about your Model. But maybe something like this will help:

```
Model.First(b=>b.GroupId!=null && b.GroupId==group.GroupId);
```

Comment: I have checked the model its not null I put 1 insted of group.GroupId and its working

Comment: And what happens if you add the b.GroupId!=null check? Could you please share the exception you get?
Looks like the information you shared is inclomplete or incorrect. Based on what you said the group.GroupId is equal to 1 and it works when you replace it with 1, but doesn't work with group.GroupId. It shouldn't be like that. Either the code is being called several times with different values, or you debug info is not correct. I would suggest to put narrow down the issue by simplifying the Model and groups.

Comment: yes exacly this weerd . b.GroupId!=null  didnt work  . its seems to me group.GroupId is like a read only varible it has a value but I cant set the value to any other varible . I added the model to my question

Comment: I added an image please look at it

Comment: Sorry daniel, but I am still confused. I understand how you determine the group.GroupId value (1). How do you check the value of a? Why don't you try to use a instead of group.GroupId since you get it in a separate statement?
I still do not see where you are getting exception and what is it's text. Could you please share it?
Those are Entity Framework, so it might be important how you get the data. I believe you have a problem, but I can't really see it so far. Your initial message states that there is a problem with b.GroupId, but you are looking at group.GroupId and I don't understand why.

Comment: i found the problem its beacuse a foreach loop is readonly and i cant use iterator.but still i dont know what to do insted